# How do I enable Personal Hotspot in the OS X WiFi menu?

Tags: macos, tethering

I have two Macs: my work MacBook Pro (retina, 15-inch, mid-2014) and my personal MacBook Air (13-inch, bought July 2013). Both are running OS X 10.10.3. When I click on the WiFi menu on my Pro, I see "Personal Hotspot":

[image]

It's showing my iPhone 6, running iOS 8.3.

But I don't see that on my Air.

How do I enable Personal Hotspot on my Air?

Comment: Under `System Preferences > Sharing` is **Internet Sharing** enabled on your Macbook Air?

Comment: That's something else Ian

Comment: FYI, Internet Sharing is off on my Pro, on which Personal Hotspot works. (It's also off on my Air.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mac and iPhone need to have the same iCloud account set up.

If they do, and it's still not visible remove the account from and re-configure it on the device that's behaving unexpectedly.

Comment: Both Macs and my iPhone are using the same iCloud account.

Comment: Mine used to have the same issue. I had to delete and re-setup iCloud on the mac.

Answer (score 3):

I have been trying to fix hotspot on my wifes iPhone 6 and MBA, it would not work most of the time.  I noticed the difference on mine that I had a hotspot section like above, where hers had her phone in the regular wifi section.  Signing out of iCloud on the mac and signing in again fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by resetting my Mac's Bluetooth module. I have described what I did in an [answer to another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/396380/235182).